# Jabber-net Client App for IOS(MonoTouch) and Android(MonoDroid) using Xamarin

Tags: c#, xmpp, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am trying to implement chat message service using Jabber-net.dll (for mono) in my app(First version already in market developed in Xamarin). I have just added Jabber library in my project and try to login using following code.

```
JabberClient jc = new JabberClient();
jc.User = "basit";   // just the username, not including the @domain.
jc.Server = "jabber.org";
jc.Password = "sdsoltest";
//jc.NetworkHost = "talk.l.google.com";
jc.Login();
```

But getting this error: 
`Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type`jabber.client.JabberClient' from `jabber-net, Version=2.1.0.710, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=924c5b18328d6f09' (CS0584)`

how can i resolve this error?

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this @Basit Zla ?

Comment: I have downloaded the source code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) and compile the source code again for mono, but no success. code compiles properly but app crashes. i will try this again.
Another solutions [here](http://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/) but quite expensive.

Comment: Did you have any success with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you download the source or binaries?

You likely will need to recompile the source for Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.Android project.

It looks like the project may be a little outdated, so you may need to spend some time setting up a new project and adding the source to compile everything.

Comment: I downloaded both, Now i am gonna recompile source as you said.

Comment: Can't add any of the JabberNet projects to Xamarin Studio :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're hitting is due to trying to reference a normal .NET assembly from a Xamarin.Android app, which tends to be a recipe for pain. The best approach is to create builds for libraries against each platform that you want to target.

If you look in the JabbR repository on GitHub you'll find there are already client projects for both [Xamarin.iOS](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR/tree/master/JabbR.Client.iOS) and [Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR/tree/master/JabbR.Client.Android). If you build and reference these you will be able to use them from your Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android apps.

Comment: Thank your for your reply and links, i will try this on Monday in office.

Comment: JabbR and Jabber is different from each other.
JabbR is based on SignalR technology. While i need XMPP

Comment: Ah yes, I'm well aware that they are different but had misread the question initially. Sorry about that!